# split one array have two key split into two array in php

Tags: php, arrays

**Question :**

I have one `array` have two key or more split into two or more create `array`  based on `array in php`.

```
my Array :



array
(

    [RAJAHMUNDRY] => Array
        (
            [unspcp_code] => 46182005
            [title] => 3M™ Half Face Reusable Respirator HF-52 with Holder 1700 And Filter 1744
            [total] => 2
            [head_quarter] => RAJAHMUNDRY
            [0] => 2
        )


        [HYDERABAD] => Array
        (
            [unspcp_code] => 46182005
            [title] => 3M™ 6200 HALF FACE MASK WITH 7093 FILTER
            [total] => 2
            [head_quarter] => HYDERABAD
            [0] => 2
        )
)
```

I want output like this :

```
output:

array
(
      [RAJAHMUNDRY] => Array
        (
            [unspcp_code] => 46182005
            [title] => 3M™ Half Face Reusable Respirator HF-52 with Holder 1700 And Filter 1744
            [total] => 2
            [head_quarter] => RAJAHMUNDRY
            [0] => 2
        )

        )
)

array(
  [HYDERABAD] => Array
        (
            [unspcp_code] => 46182005
            [title] => 3M™ 6200 HALF FACE MASK WITH 7093 FILTER
            [total] => 2
            [head_quarter] => HYDERABAD
            [0] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also don't tag spam, is it `codeigniter` or `cakephp`?

Comment: codeigniter code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[php.net - arrays manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) Example #6 Accessing array elements
Maybe this document will help you

This may also help you

```
<?php 
$stdArray = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42 => 24,
    "dimensional" => array(
        "fname" => "jon",
        "lname" => "doe",
    ),
    "multi" => array(
        "RAJAHMUNDRY" => array(
            "unspcp_code" => 46182005,
            "head_quarter" => "RAJAHMUNDRY",
            0 => 2
        ),
        "HYDERABAD" => array(
            "unspcp_code" => 46182005,
            "head_quarter" => "HYDERABAD",
            0 => 2
        ),
    )
); 

print_r($stdArray);
print_r($stdArray["multi"]);
print_r($stdArray["multi"]["RAJAHMUNDRY"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to store those arrays, but let me help you.

I assume you have a datastructure like this, so **one array** with **multiple** values.

```
array (
   key1 => ...values...,
   key2 => ...values...,
   ...
   key_n => ...values...
)
```

And you want something like this, si **multiple arrays** with **single keys** well you need to store that array somehow.

```
array (
   key1 => ...values...
)
array (
   key2 => ...values...
)
...
array (
   key_n => ...values...
)
```

If you do not know the **exact** number of arrays, you can't `$array1, $array2, ... $array_n` and it also not efficent, so you shoudl have an array of arrays. So something like this:

```
array(
    array (
       key1 => ...values...
    )
    array (
       key2 => ...values...
    )
    ...
    array (
       key_n => ...values...
    )
)
```

So you should iterate trough the keys of the input array and then
**So the code**

```
<?php

//example input array
$arr = array (
    "key1" => "val1",
    "key2" => "val2"
);

$keys = array_keys($arr); //get the keys of the input array, see phpdoc

$output = [];
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $output[] = array ($arr[$key]);
}

?>
```

This will output an array of arrays, with single key of the inner array.
If this is not you answer, reply.

Research:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php